# How to make the login screen be in portrait mode?

Tags: 11.10, login-screen, lightdm

Since I upgraded from 11.04 to 11.10, my login screen reverted back to landscape mode, and only goes to portrait mode (what I want) once I login.

How to make the login screen be in portrait mode?

Comment: Also raised in: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/812171/ But tagged as 'invalid' (not a bug).

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on a CLEAN install of 11.10:

1. BACK UP your "xorg.conf" file ("/etc/X11/xorg.conf");
2. Again, make sure you performed the step 1 above. I can't stress this enough;
3. Edit your "xorg.conf" file, adding the following to the "Device" section:

   ```
   Option  "Rotate"   "CCW"
   ```

   (`CCW` is for counter-clockwise.  Enter `CW` for clockwise);
4. Save, and restart X

Side-effect: I assume you have

```
Option   "RandRRotation"   "on"
```

in your "xorg.conf" file (I don't know how you'd be able to get a portrait display after logging in otherwise).

The only side effect I've noticed is that every time you use APT or Synaptic to install anything, and follow the process in the terminal screen, you'll get lots of "RandR extension not found" messages. It hasn't had any detrimental effects on my end.